# How to implement a save image feature on my GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, save

I have a GUI which has two text fields displaying the real and imaginary values for a complex number along with an image of the mandelbrot set. These fields show the complex number relative to mouse position on the screen. I then create a new image called a Julia set based on these values in a  different window. I am now trying to implement a save image feature so that users can save their favourite julia set image and display it again if they wish.

I have created a new window that has a grid layout with a save image to button and a display image button. So when the save image to button is clicked it will save that image to the corresponding display image button. Then when the user clicks on that display image button, it will display the julia set corresponding to the complex numbers that were saved using the save image button.

Here is how I have tried to do this in my dispaySave method:

```
public void displaySave(final JTextField jt, final JTextField jt2) {

     Point p = new Point(0, 730);

    final Double d11, d12;

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Saved Images");
    Container pane = window.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,2));

    JButton j1 = new JButton("Save to Image 1");
    j1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            d11 = Double.parseDouble(jt.getText());
            d12 = Double.parseDouble(jt2.getText());
        }
    });  

    JButton jb1 = new JButton("Display Image 1");
    jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JuliaDisplay jd = new JuliaDisplay(d11, d12);
        }
    });  

    pane.add(j1);
    pane.add(jb1);

    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setLocation(p);
    window.setSize(2200, 300);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Although there is only option for one image to be saved here my actual class has the option to save 8. Eclipse keeps telling me to make my double d11, d12 final but then when I do that it tells me to make them unfinal and I do not know how to resolve this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try to declare d11 and d12 as instance scope variables, not method scope variables.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick